# finding possible combinations linq

Tags: c#, linq, permutation

I need to generate all possible combinations between `{"a", "b","c"}`.

For example, an input set say like `{"a", "b","c"}`, expected output is `{"a", "b", "c" "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc"}`.

Comment: what have you tried so far? - this does not look like a problem that Linq is terribly well suited to. Plain old iterations are the way to go.

Comment: Well i have tried using [Cartesian product] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) from Eric Lippert, which is not helping .

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is basically a form of [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). Here's a simple implementation (taken from [this site](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23)):

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
           select
               from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
               where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
               select list[i];
}
```

Note that thanks to the `<<` operator, you won't be able to use this method with lists that have more than 30 elements. I wouldn't recommend trying it with a list with close to that many elements anyway, since at 30 elements, the result set would contain 2<sup>30</sup> or 1073741824 elements.

You can use this method to get the result you want like this

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(IList<string> strings)
{
    return from s in strings.GetPowerSet()
           select string.Concat(s);
}
```

However, because the power set includes the null set, this will actually return the result `{"", "a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc"}`. To filter out the empty string, use this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(IList<string> strings)
{
    return from s in strings.GetPowerSet()
           let str = string.Concat(s)
           where str.Length > 0 // exclude null set result
           select str;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPermutations(IList<string> strings)
{
    return from s in strings.GetPowerSet().Skip(1)
           select string.Concat(s);
}
```