# how to use where clause with sum clause in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to get a list from prices list where sum of the values equals to the value which I want.
Let me explain with example.

```
List<int> prices= new List{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> filteredList = GetSumList(4); // get list where the sum equals to 4, 1-3 or just 4. it doesn't matter which one.
```

How to write that `GetSumList(int sum)` function.

Comment: First find all permutations ([this has been solved before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470672/finding-possible-combinations-linq)) then filter the permutations to ones where the sum is 4.

Comment: @DStanley: that's an exponential approach, you can do this more efficient with dynamic programming...

Comment: @kundra: is the list guaranteed to be integral?

Comment: LINQ does not provide built-in facilities for solving [0/1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem).

Comment: @CommuSoft Pseudo-polynomial solution may very well be less efficient, especially in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: in terms of memory consumption, yes. In terms of speed, it is guaranteed (if you implement it properly) to be at least as efficient as exponential approach.

Comment: @CommuSoft do you have an example of a sub-exponential algorithm? My initial thoughts were alongside D Stanleys.

Comment: `List<int> p = prices.Where(x => prices.Any(y => y + x == sum || x == sum)).ToList();` This will return the possible numbers that can produce the sum. this will work but i did not answer as this question is considered low quality

Comment: @BenKnoble: it is pseudo-polynomial, which means poly in the size of the sum: you start with an empty set, you attach `0` to, so the memory reads `<0,{}>`. Now you upgrade your list with the first integer you encounter: `<0,{}>,<1,{1}>`. Now the next one `<0,{}>,<1,{1}>,<2,{2}>,<3,{1,2}>`. Now you upgrade with `3`, but now a nice thing happens: there are two threes, and you only hold one: `<0,{}>,<1,{1}>,<2,{2}>,<3,{3}>,<4,{1,3}>,<5,{2,3}>`. Eventually you will return the one with the correct sum. Given the values are only positive, you can emit all sets above the required value.

Comment: @BenKnoble: this is a technique called dynamic programming. The question actually deals with a variant of the *knapsack* problem.

Comment: @CommuSoft thank you. It took me a second to read the notation as <sum, set> but i eventually got it. Doesnt this still generate all possible subsets on some level? You can trash the unnecessary ones but still have created them.

Comment: @BenKnoble: No because you removed `<3,{1,2}>` immediately. Therefore you removed a node in the beginning of the process, and this will prevent the generation of an exponential amount of "children" (so to speak). Since you only store sets with sums ranging from `0` up to `r` (with `r` the requested sum), you will generate a maximum of `r*m` subsets with `m` the number of integers: each "generation" you will generate at most `r` new sets, but most of them will be removed immediately.

Comment: @BenKnoble: see the answer, if you do a complexity analysis, simply on the syntax of the program, you will see that the upperbound is linear with the requested sum and the number of elements.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't see what *LINQ* has to do with this, you can easily implement an extension method. This is more or less what *LINQ* does if I understand correctly (together with a mini language).

Comment: @CommuSoft Question title specifically asks about LINQ, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: fair point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requested **sum won't be that large**; and **all items are positive** (zero is allowed), and you don't mind much about memory, you can use the following approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetSumList(this IEnumerable<int> values, int sum) {
    List<int>[] sets = new List<int>[sum+1];
    sets[0] = new List<int>();
    foreach(int xi in values) { //O(N*sum*N) with N the number of items
        List<int> f0, f1, f2;
        for(int i = sum-xi; i >= 0; i--) { //O(N*sum)
            f0 = sets[i];
            f1 = sets[i+xi];
            if(f0 != null && (f1 == null || f0.Count < f1.Count-1)) {
                f2 = new List<int>(f0);//make clone, O(N)
                f2.Add(xi);
                sets[i+xi] = f2;
            }
        }
    }
    return sets[sum];
}
```

(if no such sum exists, `null` is returned; this algorithm will also return the *smallest* subset if any).

The algorithm makes use of *dynamic programming* and considers a list of *sets*. Each with a distinct *sum*. You can do it a bit faster if you use a *linked list* instead of `List<int>`s when calculating the temporary values, since this allows (shared) cloning and insertions in the head in O(1).

**Demo** (with the `csharp` interactive shell):

```
csharp> List<int> prices= new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }); 
csharp> prices.GetSumList(4);                                                              
{ 4 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(6); 
{ 2, 4 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(7); 
{ 3, 4 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(8); 
{ 3, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(9); 
{ 4, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(10);
{ 2, 3, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(11); 
{ 2, 4, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(12); 
{ 3, 4, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(13); 
{ 1, 3, 4, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(14); 
{ 2, 3, 4, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(15); 
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
csharp> prices.GetSumList(16); 
null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lists of lists you can do a very simple LINQ extension method like so.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lists = new List<List<int>>
        {
            new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }, // 6
            new List<int> { 3 }, // 3
            new List<int> { 3, 3 }, // 6
            new List<int> { 1, 2 }, // 3
            new List<int> { 6 } // 6
        };

        Console.WriteLine(lists.GetSumList(6).Count); // 3
    }
}

public static class ListHelpers
{
    public static List<List<int>> GetSumList(this List<List<int>> list, int sum)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x.Sum() == sum).ToList();
    }
}
```